# Returning a partial view from controller action via ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

NET MVC Project.It might look like a basic question,but I need some clarification.Which approach is better to return huge chunks of data from controller action,either by returning a whole partial view or returning a Json result when we make ajax request to the controller action.In terms of performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider three aspects:

- server processing (to retrieve the data from the data store and render it as partial view, or JSON)
- network transfer time (from server to the client browser)
- client side rendering

The network transfer time is an order of magnitude (or two, or more) larger than any of the other two. So, for large amount of data it would probably be best to return the data in as "raw" format as possible, JSON being very convenient for most purposes.

If you are returning the data as JSON, the server would not need to spend time to render HTML with your data, it would be done by the client browser, presumably using your Javascript function called when the data is received.

Different points can be made which data rendering (into HTML) would be faster: server's or browser's, but either way those savings would be negligible comparing to the savings you'd get by transferring the "raw" data.

If the data amount is not that large, performance difference would not be something the end user would be able to appreciate. In that case I'd go with most elegant solution that fits your case, or something you feel most comfortable implementing and maintaining.

Comment: Thank you Floremin for the Response.I successfully rendered the partial by making action method to return partial view after an ajax call.But after going through your response it seems,this approach is not a good idea for huge chunks of data,In terms of performance.Do you think Using Handlebars.js(JavaScript templeting) is the best way to huge amount of Json response?Are there any efficient alternative approches?

Comment: If you have already developed with partial views, I'd just leave it and optimize later. To answer your question: I'm not familiar with any Javascript template frameworks, but it might be a good idea if you're working on a project that handles lots of different data types on multiple pages. I usually create custom Javascript handler that copies an existing/hidden element(s) on the page. However, I only had to deal with fairly simple sets of data, so this was a viable approach.